# Work Energy Theorem and projectiles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, projectile

I am having trouble with my homework problem. I know how to do it with the projectile motion equations but I don't know how to solve it using the work energy theorem. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what formula to use or how to derive it using another one.
The question is:

> Use the work energy theorem to find the speed of a rock thrown downward at an intial velocity of 10 m/s from a 30 meter high cliff right before it hits the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work done by the gravitational field on the rock is equal to the change in the rock's kinetic energy. Considering the gravity acceleration as constant and equal to $g$, the gravitational force is constant and equal to $mg$, where $m$ is the rock mass. Then the work done is $W=mgh=30mg$. The variation in kinetic energy is $\Delta K= \frac{1}{2}mv_f^2-\frac{1}{2}mv_i^2=\frac{m}{2}(v_f^2-10^2)$, where $v_f$ is the rock's velocity right before it hits the ground and $v_i=10$ m/s is the initial velocity. Now you only need using the Work-energy theorem $W=\Delta K$ to determine $v_f$.